# Merging relative paths based on URL template

Tags: python, url, path

I am trying to merge user-provided URL relative paths and file paths. For example, if I am given the following items:

```
url_base = 'http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files'
path = 'path/to/files/foo.txt'
```

The desired output would be

```
http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files/foo.txt
```

Where the common path elements between the URL and file have been merged; `my/path/to/files` and `path/to/files/foo.txt` combine to give `my/path/to/files/foo.txt`, which is appended back to the base of the URL.

The closest I could get was this:

```
# python 2.7
import os
import urlparse
from collections import OrderedDict

url_base = 'http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files'
path = 'path/to/files/foo.txt'

url = urlparse.urlparse(url_base)
print(url)
# ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='myserver.com', path='/my/path/to/files', params='', query='', fragment='')

merge_path = os.path.join(url.path, path)
print(merge_path)
# /my/path/to/files/path/to/files/foo.txt

# take an ordered set of the path components
# this is not good because it assumes '/' is the split key
merge_path_set = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(merge_path.split('/')))
print(merge_path_set)
# ['', 'my', 'path', 'to', 'files', 'foo.txt']

path_joined = os.path.join(*merge_path_set)
print(path_joined)
# my/path/to/files/foo.txt

# THIS DOESN'T WORK:
url_joined = urlparse.urljoin(url.netloc, path_joined)
print(url_joined)
# my/path/to/files/foo.txt
```

It seems like there should be a better way to do this that utilizes builtin libraries instead of manually splitting on `'/'` and taking an ordered set, as I did here. I also haven't figured out how to get it back into the URL for output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`urljoin()` works fine if you bring the second argument into line with the path component of `url_base`.

For Python 2.7:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

url_base = 'http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files'
path = 'path/to/files/foo.txt'

final_url = urljoin(url_base, '/my/' + path)

# http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files/foo.txt
```

For Python 3:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url_base = 'http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files'
path = 'path/to/files/foo.txt'

final_url = urljoin(url_base, '/my/' + path)

# http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files/foo.txt
```

Assuming the `path/to/files` of `path` will always match the `path/to/files` component of `url_base`, and that you can append a '/' to the `url_base`, and though it does use a variation of `split`, you can do:

```
import os
from urlparse import urljoin

url_base = 'http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files/'
path = 'path/to/files/foo.txt'

final_url = urljoin(url_base, os.path.split(path)[-1])

print(final_url)
# http://myserver.com/my/path/to/path/to/files/foo.txt
```

Comment: In this case ,`'/my/'` is hard coded, so you can't use this in a program with variable inputs

Comment: Can you add to your question to illustrate exactly what your constraints are? As written, it seems to imply that `http://myserver.com/my/` is a constant component of `url_base`. I'll adjust my answer with more information. Cheers!

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I'm still unclear on why `final_url = urljoin(url_base, '/my/' + path)` won't work for you? If it is indeed hardcoded, this code is exactly what seems to be called for. All this is doing is saying that, to merge the paths, remember that `/my/` _is_ in fact hard-coded, and merge the paths with that in consideration. You're basically telling `urljoin` to keep '/my/' when merging the two `path/to/files/foo.txt` paths. Or rather, another way of saying it is to say 'merge these two paths as if `/my/` weren't there.' With your modified question, it seems even _more_ exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Still another way of putting it: by using `'/my/' + path`, you are showing `urljoin` how you want your "variable inputs" to be merged with the url. Your question seems to imply that you want to take `http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files/` and `path/to/files/foo.txt` and merge them to end up with `http://myserver.com/my/path/to/files/foo.txt` and that `http://myserver.com/my/` will remain constant. That's exactly what this code does. Can you explain what I'm missing here by clarifying your question a bit more?

Comment: Did you get this working? Just wanting to know if this was helpful.